# How to ConfigureServices in Asp.Net core WebAPI from another assembly

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, pact-net

In a microservice environment I need to construct a framework for Contract based testing.
I'm currently investigatingh how to isolate a single service from it's external dependencies inorder to execute the Provider tests.

What I need to do is:

- Keep the WebApi project intact
- Start an instance of the WepApi with some config-differences
- Mock out selected dependencies

My Solution structure is this:

```
Case-Solution/  
├── src/  
|   ├──Case.Api  
|   └──Case.Application  
├── test/  
|   ├──Case.Api.Unittest  
|   ├──(other tests)  
|   ├──Case.Pact.CunsumerTest  
|   └──Case.Pact.ProviderTest
```

I've read [this](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net) guide about Pact Tests in dotnet.
Focusing on `Case.Pace.ProviderTest`, I need to start `Case.Api` programmatically from `Case.Pact.ProviderTest` (and another WebHost for Pact it self) and substitute some of it dependencies.

So far I got this:

```cs
public class ProviderApiTests : IDisposable
{
    private string ProviderUri { get; }
    private string PactServiceUri { get; }
    private IWebHost PactServiceWebHost { get; }
    private IWebHost CasesWebHost { get; }
    private ITestOutputHelper OutputHelper { get; }
    public static IConfiguration CaseConfiguration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();


    public ProviderApiTests(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        OutputHelper = output;
        ProviderUri = "http://localhost:9000";
        PactServiceUri = "http://localhost:9001";

        CasesWebHost = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseUrls(ProviderUri)
            .UseStartup<CaseStartup>()
            .UseConfiguration(CaseConfiguration)
            .Build();
        CasesWebHost.Start();

        PactServiceWebHost = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseUrls(PactServiceUri)
            .UseStartup<ProviderServerStartup>()
            .Build();
        PactServiceWebHost.Start();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void EnsureProviderApiHonoursPactWithConsumer()
    {
        //Arrange
        var config = new PactVerifierConfig
        {
            Outputters = new List<IOutput>
            {
                new XUnitOutput(OutputHelper)
            },
            Verbose = true,
            CustomHeader = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("X-apikey", "XXX")
        };
        //Act //Assert
        IPactVerifier pactVerifier = new PactVerifier(config);
        pactVerifier.ProviderState($"{PactServiceUri}/provider-states")
            .ServiceProvider("CaseProvider", ProviderUri)
            .HonoursPactWith("CaseConsumer")
            .PactUri(@"..\..\..\..\..\pacts\caseconsumer-caseprovider.json")
            .Verify();
    }
    #region IDisposable Support
    //IDisposable code
    #endregion
}
```

In the line containing `.UseStartup<CaseStartup>()` I've simply copied `Startup.cs` from `Case.Api` and changed the needed dependencies, which works fine.

But I want a more generic solution. It's doesn't feel right to just copy code and call it a day :) because it is not generic and reusable for the other services.

So I kept digging, and came up with the following.

**Add Controllers from other assembly**
I realised, that starting a IWebhost, using StartUp from a different assembly, doesn't automagically add controller from that assembly. This needs to be done explicitly. So I did this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.Load("Case.Api");
    services.AddMvc()
       .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
       .AddApplicationPart(assembly)
       .AddControllersAsServices();
    ......
}
```

Awesome!!! So far so good.

Next issue:

**Replace dependencies:**
Reding [this](https://reasoncodeexample.com/2016/08/16/setting-up-integration-tests-using-the-asp-net-core-webhostbuilder/) article, I created the extension method for replacing dependencies:

```cs
public static void Replace<TRegisteredType>(this IServiceCollection services, TRegisteredType replcement)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < services.Count; i++)
    {
        if (services[i].ServiceType == typeof(TRegisteredType))
        {
            services[i] = new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(TRegisteredType), replcement);
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm able to replace the dependencies I want like so: (in this case a QueryHandler)

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    .....
    var queryHandler = Substitute.For<IQueryHandler<Query, QueryResult>>();
    queryHandler.Handle(Arg.Any<Query>()).Returns(new QueryResult(...));
    services.Replace(queryHandler);
    ......
}
```

But this doesn't solve my issue with copied code.

My wet dream is to be able to use `Startup.cs` from `Case.Api` and somehow tweak the DI to replace the dependencies, without having all the redundant code.

Any input would be highly appriciated.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation also using Pact.net. But I wanted to use [TestServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0), unfortunately Pact.net does not have support for httpClient ( [Verifying pact with in-memory API](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net/issues/240) ). At the end I use a combination of two libraries, probably not the best to validate all scenarios. I took the consumer part of Pact.net to generate the contract and the [Verifier](https://github.com/snatch-dev/Pactify/blob/master/src/Pactify/PactVerifier.cs) part of [Pactify](https://github.com/snatch-dev/Pactify) to verify if the provider is honoring the contract. The Verifier requires code modification to be compatible with the Pact.net contract though.

I also used your code example to replace dependencies for mocks using moq.

```
[TestClass]
public class EndpointShouldHonorContract
{

    private HttpClient httpClient;
    private ApiWebApplicationFactory<Startup> testServerFactory;
    Mock<IRepository> repositoryMock =
        new Mock<IRepository>();

    public EndpointShouldHonorContract()
    {
        //omitting code... Creation of mock Data Set https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking?redirectedfrom=MSDN#testing-query-scenarios
        repositoryMock.Setup(s => s.GetQueryable()).Returns(mockDataSet.Object);

        testServerFactory = new ApiWebApplicationFactory<Startup>(services => 
        {
            services.Replace<IRepository>(repositoryMock.Object);
        });

        httpClient = testServerFactory.CreateClient();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task HonorContract() 
    {
          // this is my modified Pactify Verifier 
           await MyModifiedPactify
            .VerifyPact
            .PactVerifier
            .Create(httpClient)
            .Between("consumer", "provider")
            //location of contract, there is also an option where you can get contracts from a http location
            .RetrievedFromFile(@"\Pacts")
            .VerifyAsync();
    }
 }
```

Web Api Factory : here I use your extension to replace dependencies

```
public class ApiWebApplicationFactory<TStartUp>
    : WebApplicationFactory<TStartUp> where TStartUp: class
{

    Action<IServiceCollection> serviceConfiguration { get; }

    public ApiWebApplicationFactory(Action<IServiceCollection> serviceConfiguration) : base()
    {
        this.serviceConfiguration = serviceConfiguration;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        if (this.serviceConfiguration != null)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(this.serviceConfiguration);
        }
    }


}

internal static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void Replace<TRegisteredType>(this IServiceCollection services, TRegisteredType replacement)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < services.Count; i++)
        {
            if (services[i].ServiceType == typeof(TRegisteredType))
            {
                services[i] = new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(TRegisteredType), replacement);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Isreal, So awesome you took the time to answer this question. I'm really sorry to say that I don't have access to the source anymore and therefor cannot verify your answer :( especially when you spent so much time with this. Hope you'll keep it up :) Welcome to the community