# start asp net core webapp from console project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I got an asp.net core WebApp project.
Now I want to start that web app from another console app.

How do I do that?

I want to reuse all the configuration and DI setup from webapp.
Thanks

Comment: Asp.net core web projects by default hosted and run via console app. Is there anything you want to do specifically?

Comment: @chetan Yes. I'm trying to run contract based API testing (Pact Foundation). I need to spin up the API and tweak the DI a bit to mock dependencies to run the test.

Comment: Can you not simply use a test project and the test server? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @ChrisPratt. I did not know that existed. It looks very promising. I will have a look right now. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisPratt So I read it, and it's awesome!!! It is exactly what I needed. Thank you!
If you want; write an answer to my ealier questions and I'll give you the points (Y)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57850859/how-to-configureservices-in-asp-net-core-webapi-from-another-assembly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOTNET run command from your console app to run the Web App.

```
dotnet run --project ./projects/proj1/proj1.csproj
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore21